# D3 align text on left side of the axis from the right most character

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

So I have a D3 bar chart that looks like: [bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3UWR.png).  The problem appears for the smaller data bars when they overlap over the right side of the axis. I want to align the data text along the left side of the graph axis (as shown with the larger numbers) regardless of how small the bar is.

```
var data = [200.000001,3.00001,300.00001,1.00001,400.00001,5.0001,100.00001,20.0001,40.0001,50.00001, 2.00001];

//bar chart
var bars = d3.select("#chart").append("div").attr("class","chartstyle");
var b = bars.selectAll("div")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("div")
  .style("width", function(d) { return d  + "px"; })
  .text(function(d) { return d; });
});

//from stylesheet
<style>
.chartstyle div {
    font: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: black;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use `svg:text` elements with a `text-anchor` property set to `end` ([see spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TextAnchorProperty)) instead of mixing nodes from different namespaces.

```
var gBars = d3.select("#chart")
  .selectAll(".bar-container")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "bar-container");

// bars
gbars.append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  [...] // bars positioning and sizing logic

// labels
gBars.append("text")
  .attr("class", "bar-label")
  .attr("text-anchor", "end")
  [...] // same positioning logic
  .text(Object);
```